# Compile Error in pragma solidity 0.8.0 and others

Tags: compilation, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20, bep20

When I try to compile my bep20 smart contract it says:

> ParserError: Invalid token. --> bep-20.sol:6:53: | 6 |
> constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20(“MilkyWayGalaxy”,
> “MILKYGAL”) { | ^

I use the pragma solidity ^0.8.0; but the latest edition is pragma solidity ^0.8.4;. I have tried on all versions and still doesn't work.

Can someone help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the regular quote `"` or apostrophe `'` characters, your snippet is using the left quote `“`. *It's probably caused by copying from a website that replaces regular quotes to left quotes as a security measure.*

Also, Solidity 0.8 will throw a warning for using visibility modifier on a constructor. Remove the `public` visiblity modifier.

```
constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("MilkyWayGalaxy", "MILKYGAL") {
```

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. Now the problem it's solved. You are the best :) Thank youuuu